# Rails direct upload to s3 in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, sidekiq

I want the following workflow:

- visit /projects/new
- attach 1GB video file
- click 'submit'
- video file uploads to S3 in background while user browses rest of site

I've been using S3_file_field gem up intil now, which lets me upload directly to S3. But my boss wants the upload to happen in the background, like on Vimeo, without making the user wait on the form page until the direct upload is complete.

I had hoped that the Carrierwave Backgrounder would solve this problem, but it makes me wait for the entire file to upload when I press submit. This is not what we want. We'd like our users to be able to browse the rest of our site as soon as they click submit, and for sidekiq to do the upload in the background.

Are there any gems that let you achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

RailsCast has an episode on this:
[Rails Cast Episode 383](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/
It might work for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks like it does not let you perform the actual upload in the background, only the post-upload processing. I need the actual transfer to S3 to happen benind the scenes, so that the user wont have to wait 20 minutes for the upload to complete before they can press submit. Thanks anyway.